# Parse retrieve User

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery, pfuser

I would like to ask why the console print something like this

```
[<PFUser: 0x7fd991f4eff0, objectId: wWfeR2MZQi, localId: (null)> {
}]
```

while another print

```
<PFUser: 0x7fd991f145e0, objectId: wWfeR2MZQi, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd991f2d3f0>";
    displayName = alexander;
    email = "alexanderGGWP@LIVE.com";
    username = alexander;
}
```

, I is both PFUSer but they printed out different thing  .

Comment: is the first in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the PFUser are different (You can identify by 0x7fd991f4eff0 and 0x7fd991f145e0) but belongs to same class or say table (in Parse). And please check that either of the PFUser instance is nil of not...

Comment: But the objectId is the same

Comment: true, but both the PFUser instance are not same.

Answer (score 0):

The first PFUser looks as if it hasn't been fully fetched from the network. The second one looks as if it has.

```
[user fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error) {
NSLog(@"%@", object);
            }];
```

If you fetchIfNeeded* on the first one, does it inspect the same as the second one?